# Cisco Anyconnect issue

Tags: networking, vpn

I am trying to set-up Cisco Anyconnect on ubuntu 17.10, but I face this error:
"The AnyConnect package on the secure gateway could not be located. You may be experiencing network connectivity issues. Please try connecting again"

I have had a look around but I could not find anything useful; looks like a package is missing but no luck finding it!
Here is the links I have used for installation:

http://www.socsci.uci.edu/~jstern/uci_vpn_ubuntu/
https://uci.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0010201

Thank You! :-)

Comment: You should get into the habit of googling error messages instead of asking a question that shows zero research. That's not what we expect here. You would easily find this (it even has a video tutorial): https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000406

Comment: If I had found a good answer after googling then I would not have come here and ask this question. The link you sent hasn`t given me any result.
I think you are not aware that NOT every link you find on the internet can yield positive results,  some of them DO NOT solve the issues faced; perhaps instead of telling people what to do , you can make yourself useful and NOT post a reply as you just did.

Comment: In that case you are expected to post what you tried and what errors you got, so that we don't waste our time suggesting something you already did..

Answer (score 1):

The anycast vpnui binary needs libpangox-1.0-0 shared library; it does not need the lib32z1 and lib32ncurses5 packages (at least on my x86_64 system).

Follow the instructions in the URLs you reference however replace the "sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5" command with "sudo apt-get install libpangox-1.0-0".

Answer (score 0):

Question is old, but no good answer.

The best option is to install **openconnect**! It doesn't require any modifications on VPN-server.

```
apt install openconnect
```

Another option is to install package for your OS on VPN-server. This should be done by VPNserver admins, not you.

Your client software seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the correct version of the package. This will work for you.

I encountered the same problem when I download the correct version as per CISCO documentation. This works for me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "install the correct version of the package" so that people in the future might understand how to identify the correct version and put it on their system? A few paragraphs, with links and notes, can go a long way 